# set value of hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the value of two hidden input fields, whenever my dropdown changes.
I want to add the **new price** to the `.formamount` fields.

Currently, I have this piece of code:

```
var form_paypal = '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="form1">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $sdata['paypal_email']; ?>">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Purchase Clicks">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="" class="formamount">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="" id="pp_tax">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="aXRlbTpyZW50YWw7dToyMjQ5NjA=" id="pp_custom">'+
    '</form>';

    var form_payza = '<form method="post" action="https://secure.payza.com/checkout" id="form1">'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_purchasetype" value="service"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_merchant" value="<?php echo $sdata['alertpay_email']; ?>"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_itemname" value="Purchase Clicks"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_currency" value="USD"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_quantity" value="1"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_description" value="<?php echo $userdata['username']; ?>"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_amount" value="" class="formamount"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_returnurl" value="<?php echo $sdata['siteurl'] ?>a"/>'+
    '<input type="hidden" name="ap_cancelurl" value="<?php echo $sdata['siteurl'] ?>a"/>'+
    '</form>';

 $(function(){
    $('#clicks').change(function () {
        var cPrice = $('option:selected', this).data('price');
        $('#info-price').text($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
        $(".formamount").val(cPrice);
    }); 
   });
```

So, as you can see, the `var cPrice` gets the price from the data-attribute. Now, this is working. I know this, because if I add `alert(cPrice);` everytime the dropdown changes, it will alert me a new price.

Nothing happens to the .formamount fields. They don't add the `cPrice` value.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: you have same ids for both `forms` as i can see.

Comment: @Jai Please see: `'<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="" class="formamount">'+`

Comment: @oliverbj just saw but where is your button which gets the `click` event.

Comment: I have two buttons, one for each form. Whenever a button is pressed, the form will be submitted. Example: `$(form_paypal).submit();`

Comment: As per this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/judxC/ , there seems to be no problem. Try entering any value you want to set, then click the "set" button. Then click "check" button to see the values that have been set. Am sure, the problem is elsewhere in your code.